# How to show and hide custom error messages with jQuery Validate every time an error occurs on an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

this is how I am trying to validate my form:
HTML:

```
<form class="am-form amSignUpF">
                    <!-- Name -->
                    <div class="amSULabelCont">
                        <label for="name_f-0">Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="amSUInputContainer">
                        <div class="amSUInputErrorCont" id="error_name_f-0"></div>
                        <input id="name_f-0" class="amSignUpField amName amFormControl" type="text" name="name_f">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Surname -->
                    <div class="amSULabelCont">
                        <label for="name_l-0">Surname</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="amSUInputContainer">
                        <div class="amSUInputErrorCont" id="error_name_l-0"></div>
                        <input id="name_l-0" class="amSignUpField amSurname amFormControl" type="text" name="name_l">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Email -->
                    <div class="amSULabelCont">
                        <label for="email-0">E-mail</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="amSUInputContainer">
                        <div class="amSUInputErrorCont" id="error_email-0"></div>
                        <input id="email-0" class="amSignUpField email amEmail required amFormControl" type="text" name="email">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Password -->
                    <div class="amSULabelCont">
                        <label for="pass-0">Password</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="amSUInputContainer">
                        <div class="amSUInputErrorCont" id="error_pass-0"></div>
                        <input id="pass-0" class="amSignUpField amPassword amFormControl" type="password" name="pass">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Repeat password -->
                    <div class="amSULabelCont">
                        <label for="pass-confirm">Confirm Password</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="amSUInputContainer">
                        <div class="amSUInputErrorCont" id="error_pass-confirm"></div>
                        <input id="pass-confirm" class="amSignUpField amConfirmpassword amFormControl" type="password" name="_pass">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Conditions & Privacy -->
                    <div class="amSULabelCBttm">
                        <div class="amSUInputContainer">
                            <div class="amSUInputErrorCont" id="error_i_agree-0"></div>
                            <input id="i_agree-0" type="checkbox" name="i_agree" value="1" class="amAgree">
                            <span class="testo_08">Accept <a href="" class="brCleL" target="_blank">conditions</a> and <a href="" class="brCleL" target="_blank">privacy</a></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Submit -->
                    <button id="reg-confirm" class="btn btn-warning large" name="buttonsubmit" type="submit">Registration</button>
                </form>
```

CSS:

```
    .amSUInputContainer {
        position: relative;
}

.amSUInputErrorCont {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 99999;
        min-width: 200px;
        max-width: 500px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-size: 15px;
        left: 250px;
        top: -16px;
        border: 1px solid #962729;
        background: #CF2024;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0px #E4494D;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0px #E4494D;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0px #E4494D;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: white;
        padding: 2px 18px;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.showError {
        display: block;
}
```

And JS:

```
    $(function() {
        $(".am-form.amSignUpF").validate({
                errorElement: "div",
                errorContainer: "#errorContainer",
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                        console.log("VALIDATE");
                        var elId = element.attr("id");
                        $(".amSUInputErrorCont#error_"+elId).append(error);
        },
                success: function(errorDiv) {
                        console.log(errorDiv);
                        console.log(errorDiv.find("amSUInputErrorCont"));
                        errorDiv.find("amSUInputErrorCont").removeClass("showError");
                },
                invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
                        console.log(validator.currentElements);
                        validator.currentElements.each(function(){
                                var fieldId = $(this).attr("id");
                                $(".amSUInputErrorCont#error_"+fieldId).addClass("showError");
                        });
                }
        });

        $(".amName").rules("add", {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 50,
                messages: {
                        required: "Insert your name.",
                        minlength: "min 3 chars.",
                        maxlength: "max 50 chars."
                }
        });

        $(".amSurname").rules("add", {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 50,
                messages: {
                        required: "insert you surname.",
                        minlength: "min 3 chars.",
                        maxlength: "max 50 chars."
                }   
        });

        $(".amEmail").rules("add",{
                required: true,
                email: true,
                messages: {
                        required: "insert an e-mail address",
                        email: "insert a valid e-mail address",
                        minlength: "min 3 chars.",
                        maxlength: "max 50 chars."

                }
        });

        $(".amPassword").rules("add", {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 50,
                messages: {
                        required: "provide a password.",
                        minlength: "min 3 chars.",
                        maxlength: "max 50 chars"
                }
        });

        $(".amConfirmpassword").rules("add", {
                required: true,
                equalTo: ".amPassword",
                messages: {
                        required: "confirm the password.",
                        equalTo: "password don't match."
                }
        });


        $(".amAgree").rules("add", {
                required: true,
                messages: {
                        required: "You must agree to our <br> terms and conditions"
                }
        });

});
```

Here is the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/B5335/1/

When you click on the button "Register" and no input field has been compiled, all errors appear, the problem is that if I type inside them, the error won't disappear, when jquery calls the validate's success: callback. How can I make the errors of each error div show every time there's an error and disappear every time there are no errors on a particular input field ?

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the newest jquery validate plugin.  I updated and your example works now.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Sorry, were did you post the update?

Comment: I used your jsfiddle and changed the external resource to the newest jquery validate plugin.  So, download the newest version and try it out.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I came across another problem. I am trying to make those divs fadeIn and fadeOut depending on whether there's an error on a particular input field. The fadeIn works, the problem is that when you compile an input field respecting his rules and the previous error fades out, if you for example delete your input and then click on the reg button again, the error message won't fadeIn again, why is it behaving like this? I have updated the fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/B5335/48/

Comment: I'm not sure, if you take out all of your custom functions within validate(), it works as expected.  So it's something to do with hiding divs or removing classes.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong with something? But I can't fix it out cause the code seems right, but I have noticed that the errorPlacement: callback is called only once, i.e. only the first time I click on the "Register" button... Is there a way to trigger it every time the user clicks on the submit button or on input field blur event? In order to re-add the error message if the field is yet not correct?